Projective cover (minimal) for (derived)complete modules over Noetherian local rings exist?
Let $(R,\mathfrak  m)$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring. Let $M$ be an $R$-module which is $\mathfrak m$-adically derived complete. Then, does there exist a free $R$-module $F$ and a surjective $R$-linear map $g: F\to M$ such that $\ker g \subseteq \mathfrak m F$? If this does not hold more generally like this, I would even br happy if we assumed the stronger condition that $M$ is $\mathfrak m$-adically complete.
I only want to know for the case when $M$ is not finitely generated (for finitely generated modules, what I ask is true unconditionally without any completeness hypothesis).

What about $k[[x]][x^{-1}]$ as a module over $k[[x]]$ with $\mathfrak{m}=(x)$?

@DaveBenson: the module you say is not complete, right? It does not seem to satisfy the separability condition https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/091T
